# Order by date from two tables using Union alternative

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have this two tables

comments

```
| ID | COMMENT | FULLNAME       | PHOTO_ID |           CREATED_AT            |
|----|---------|----------------|----------|---------------------------------|
| 76 | comment1| John Smith     |       14 | February, 25 2014 10:38:02+0000 |
| 77 | comment2| James Anderson |       14 | February, 25 2014 10:38:14+0000 | 
| 78 | comment3| Will Smith     |       15 |    March, 11 2014 14:24:08+0000 |
```

views

```
| ID | USER | PID |           CREATED_AT            |
|----|------------|---------------------------------|
| 63 | user1| 15  | February, 25 2014 11:12:03+0000 |
| 64 | user1| 14  | February, 25 2014 11:14:10+0000 | 
| 66 | user2| 15  | February, 25 2014 11:15:16+0000 |
| 68 | user2| 14  | February, 25 2014 10:38:12+0000 |
```

I would like to get the values from `comments.comment`, `comments.fullname`, `views.user` so I can use them into a foreach and the results will order by date like so:

`John Smith added a comment     February, 25 2014 10:38:12 //comment1
 user2 viewed the file          February, 25 2014 10:38:12 //view
 James Anderson added a comment February, 25 2014 10:38:12 //comment2`

I'm using this query using UNION but I don't think it's the right approach since I can't use  the fullname to tell who is writing the comment or the user viewing the file

```
SELECT comment, fullname, comments.created_at
FROM comments
WHERE comments.photo_id = 14
UNION
SELECT user, '', views.created_at
FROM views
WHERE views.pid = 14
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

And the result is

```
|  COMMENT |       FULLNAME |                      CREATED_AT |
|----------|----------------|---------------------------------|
|    user1 |                | February, 25 2014 11:14:10+0000 |
| comment2 | James Anderson | February, 25 2014 10:38:14+0000 |
|    user2 |                | February, 25 2014 10:38:12+0000 |
| comment1 |     John Smith | February, 25 2014 10:38:02+0000 |
```

So, is there another way to combine this two tables, order them by date and get the rows individually?
Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8bac/3).

Comment: what is the relation between these tow tables?

Comment: there is no relation between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could give it a try…

```
SELECT IF(comment = 'view', 'view', 'comment') AS type, comment, fullname, created_at
FROM
(
  SELECT comment, fullname, comments.created_at
  FROM comments
  WHERE comments.photo_id = 14
  UNION
  SELECT 'view', user, views.created_at
  FROM views
  WHERE views.pid = 14
) tbl
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8bac/8/0)

Comment: per the OP request.. your select should be this... SELECT fullname, IF(comment = 'view', ' viewed the file ', ' added the comment ') AS type, created_at, comment

Comment: @JohnRuddell That's the kind of thing that I would rather put in the display code. You shouldn't have to update your query if you want to change the wording that is displayed. So you would have something like (assuming PHP) `echo ($resultRow["type"] == "view" ? "viewed the file" : "added the comment");`

Comment: no i gotcha on that... i was more saying the order of how you pull it out, its simpler to pull it out in the correct order so you dont have to make those changes afterwards, and if your inputing a string in the if() already its simpler to make the string what the OP wants then extra coding to change it... my normal preference though

Comment: @PatrickQ, how about adding a new table? How should I modify this statement? IF(comment = 'view', 'view', 'comment') to add `newtable` to `type` column?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    USER, ACTION, TIME
FROM
    (
    SELECT
         FULLNAME as USER
        ,'COMMENT' as ACTION
        ,CREATED_AT as TIME
    FROM comments
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
         USER as USER
        ,'VIEW' as ACTION
        ,CREATED_AT as TIME
    FROM views
    )
WHERE
    VIEWS_PID = 14
OERDER BY
    TIME DESC
```

Comment: you don't have alias's for your tables... and I don't think VIEWS_PID would work since you don't make it something